# Ionic command taking long time finally no response available.

Tags: node.js, cordova, ionic-framework

I am using node `v6.9.1`, npm `3.10.9`, cordova `6.4.0` and Ionic framework latest version in windows 7. Everything is working without `IONIC` command.
Each and every command of IONIC it just show `--------------------------------`.
nothing else even no error and nothing visible after dashes for long time(forever). How can i solve it?

```
E:\Iproject\practise>npm -v
3.10.9

E:\Iproject\practise>node -v
v6.9.1

E:\Iproject\practise>cordova -v
6.4.0

E:\Nodejs\practise\myApp>ionic -v
--------------------------------   // from here no response available
```

Comment: update your ionic or remove and add ionic again...

Comment: I have fully reinstalled everything of  npm even removed all nodejs related everything but it is not working after again. @Naitik

Comment: can you try open cmd in administrative permission then try again for **ionic -v**

Comment: Yes, it is in administrative mode.

Comment: try to run your command with cordova instead of ionic...